# Create empty IQueryable<T> for Linq to SQL and concat it later

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I would like to create an function that creates some Linq to SQL that i can later add to an existing IQueryable. For my examples i use a person(T) with the propperty Surname.

I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
var surnameFilter = GetSurnameFilter(surname);
var finalQuery = _context.Persons.Concat(filterQuery);
var persons = finalQuery.ToList();

private IQueryable<Person> GetSurnameFilter(string surname)
{
     // Create empty IQueryable<Person>
     IQueryable<Person> query = Enumerable.Empty<Person>().AsQueryable();
     return query.Where(k => k.Surname.Contains(surname));
}
```

But then i get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression
>   'EnumerableQuery { }
>       .Where(k => k.Surname.Contains(__surname_0))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate
>   either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
>   information.'

I would like this so i can choose what filter to add later on.
I know its just a little thing but i prefer to concat the filterquery to the main query for readability and ease of use. After some debugging i got it down to the cast when creating the empty `IQueryable<Person>`.
I got it to work when i do this but this is not what i want:

```
var finalQuery = AddFilter(_context.Persons, surnameFilter);
var persons= finalQuery.ToList();

private IQueryable<Person> AddFilter(IQueryable<Person> query, string surname)
{
    return query.Where(k => k.Surname.Contains(surname));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking about? If you want to add additional filters to the, you could just use `query = query.Where(x => something`). If you want to concatenate the results of two querys, execute those two querys and concatenate the result lists?

Comment: 1. It is possible to add just the where but i would like to use it as a method so i can reuse the code.
2. Then you will have 2 sql queries execute and need to compare it in memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where in all your explanation you need the empty IQueryable, where do you need to cancat and what. Just for curiosity is there any reason why this can't be an IEnumerable, in the method instead of forcing the IQueryable?

Comment: If you use IEnumerable the data will be handled on the server and not on the sql database by sql. Sql is faster and internal memory will be saved. In general if you work with a lot of data you need to ensure the linq to sql because sql can handle data much better and less data goes over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could accomplish something like this with [Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

I have the following model

```cs
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int) (TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

I can then create an Extension class that contains methods for this specific type:

```cs
    public static class WeatherForecastExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<WeatherForecast> AddFilter(this IQueryable<WeatherForecast> queryable, string str)
        {
            return queryable
                .Where(forecast => forecast.Summary != null)
                .Where(forecast => forecast.Summary.Contains(str));
        }
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```cs
            var forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();
            var filtered = forecasts.AsQueryable()
                .AddFilter("cold")
                .ToList();
```

Keep in mind that these extension will only work for `IQueryable`s that contain a `Weatherforecast` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this does work (I already have this inplace atm) but not what i am looking for. I dont want to split the code over multiple files for readability . Because this is an extention you will it has to go into another class. I would like to have an empty filter query to concat lateron (To whatever other _context.persons i have at the moment).